# Eclipse m2e not generating Maven Libraries for Java Resources

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I am currently trying to create a m2e maven-archtype-webapp project in Eclipse, but I notice that it does not generate the Maven Libraries under the Java Resources directory.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ord.code.ranch</groupId>
  <artifactId>somewebapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>somewebapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>somewebapp</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Eclipse Juno - Project Explorer
[image: Eclipse Juno - Project Explorer]

Comment: What is it that you expect exactly?

Comment: Well it should add the Maven Library dependency. Sorry about the screenshot, but it only add a JRE Library dependency